# Skype does not work after upgrading to Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, skype, windows-8.1-upgrade

I upgraded my Windows 8 to 8.1, but now Skype does not start. I downloaded Skype again, but the symptoms are the same - after starting Skype it disappears after a few seconds.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

There is a windows update released (today) that fixes this problem.

Hotfix (**[KB2902892](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2902892)**) to fix Skype app crashes in Windows 8.1

> When you start the Skype Windows Store app in Windows 8.1 or in
>   Windows Server 2012 R2, the app immediately crashes, and Windows
>   returns to the Start screen. This issue occurs when the computer uses
>   an Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000 (Sandy Bridge) graphics device,"
>   Microsoft stated on its support page

Comment: Which one, is there a KB reference?

Answer (score 0):

Does Skype disappear after login, or before login?

If it disappears after login, try removing your Skype profile folder:

- Make sure there are no more Skype processes running.
- Go to `%appdata%\Skype`
- Remove the folder with your skype name.
- Start Skype again

If it disappears before you have a chance to login. Try to remove skype completely:

- Download the Free version of [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/)
- Remove skype, and be sure to remove any leftovers Revo may find.
- Install Skype again

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall .NET 3.5. Simply go to Control Panel > Programs and Features, then click Turn Windows features on or off and in the new window deselect .NET Framework 3.5. Click OK and let windows remove .NET 3.5 hen it's finished, go to the same place and check .NET 3.5 checkbox again. Click ok. Now Skype should work.